# Using constructor declaration as a virtual function

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am not sure whether the question title is appropriate with respect to the details below.

I am working with a number of datasets which are widely different. So, I conceptualised that I would create a Base class "Dataset", from which "Dataset1", "Dataset2" etc would inherit. Now the situation is as follows:-

I want to have a uniform constructor as follows :-

Dataset(std::string category, )

So, for each dataset class I want to initialize them with category as the first argument and other variable arguments (which depend upon specific dataset).

My question is :-

Can I have a virtual constructor function in Dataset class, which can be inherited by "Dataset1", "Dataset2" and so on ? Is this the right design choice ? How do I implement it (variable arguments etc ) ?

Comment: A constructor is part of a specific class. When you call a constructor, you have already decided the specific class you want. So if your problem requires you to decide the class *based on the value of one of the arguments*, then class constructors are not the right place for this. (Perhaps you want some kind of factory function.)

Comment: Simple answer is NO. There's no such thing like a `virtual` constructor.

Comment: So, my situation is pertaining to a factory design pattern ? I would read up on it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: A Stack Overflow version of "Simon Says"? `{"Noo", "Use JQuery", "Off-topic"}`?

Comment: @KerrekSB My tablet's own life ;-) ... They've been building some text recognition KI with it, I don't appreciate most of the time.

Comment: Please, show us an example of what you are thinking. Because it may be that what you need is to use an interface, a factory method or a strategy pattern.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nice idea anyway, maybe my tablet isn't as dumb as I think it is :-D ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for the existence of unicorns is useless in the commonly accepted scientific context.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Before you use your powers to simply close questions, please know that no everyone is on the same level of proficiency. There are a whole lot of even dumber programming questions on Stackoverflow. These conceptual questions are the real doubts most beginning and intermediate programmers face. So, either make stackoverflow  meant only for great coders, or don't declare such questions off-topic in a condescending way.

Comment: @UjjwalAryan Research before applying unsolicited critique on comments or votes please! Research can be expected from everyone hitting up here, no matter, if they're experienced with the topic or not?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did research. But please understand that it is difficult sometimes on some issues for people (and even good ones!!) to clearly phrase something. I also work in some area in which I am very good at. If someone asks a not-so-accurate question in that area, I would rather direct the person in the right direction rather than simply pass remarks. Thanks

Comment: @UjjwalAryan So you rather want me applying my powers to mark your question as a duplicate of [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5Dvirtual+constructor)?? No, you're not convincing me regarding your research efforts shown in your question. I'm out of downvotes today, that's the only reason your question is limboing at a state of zero score yet.

Comment: @UjjwalAryan If you have any doubts, you might want to discuss this on [Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While C++ doesn't have virtual constructors, 'virtual constructor' is a well-known (albeit not preferred by me) design pattern. You can google it up, it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have a lot of experience with design patterns. So perhaps it was a dumb question for many, but it helps to know the factory design pattern. Thank you :)

Comment: @UjjwalAryan Just one thing - factory and virtual constructor are actually slightly different. Classic factory creates an object by analyzing it'

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a virtual constructor in C++. See http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual-ctor Constructors of superclasses should be called when constructing an object of a subclass